# Determine time since last input in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm building an arcade cabinet and would like to have random games launch after 15 minutes of inactivity. I'm not sure how to determine the time since the last user input. This is a pretty standard screensaver with xserver, however I can't seem to find a way to do it without x running.

Specifically I'm running RetroPie on a Raspberry Pi 2. X is installed but not running. The front end is emulationstation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Last user input to what? Where is the input happening?

Comment: Any input. It'll mostly be from a joystick (4 buttons) or 10 arcade buttons.

There is some code that I'm running that recognizes when these buttons are pressed and converts them into keyboard commands. I'm toying with the idea of using that to store the current UNIX time in an ENV variable. Then using cron to check every couple of minutes to see how much time has elapsed. I don't think that is very efficient.

That method would also ignore any keyboard or xbox controller input. So I was hoping for a battle tested option before rolling my own.